# ArcGIS Can't get ResultImageLayer

Tags: arcgis-server, geoprocessing

I am unable to get a ResultImageLayer.

I can get a GPFeatureRecordSetLayer using ResultData and add the feature geometries individually.

I am using ArcServer 10.1 so it is not a pre-release problem.

I can see the map service that accompanies the geoprocessing service and the legend / symbology in this map service.

I am doing this with the JavaScriptAPI.

Using Firefox I see a “500 Internal Server Error” but there is no other messages.
Could be as simple as my call:

gp2.getResultImageLayer(jobInfo.jobId, "Test01", imageParameters, addGPServiceResult2, errorProcessing)
function addGPServiceResult2(gpImageLayer) {
   map.addLayer(gpImageLayer);
}

I’m not sure what the ParameterName “Test01” should refer to although I’ve tried ever possibility that seemed reasonable.

Or could be an ArcServer setting?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Charles

Comment: If you go to the web page for the gp service, is there a Test01 parameter?  Is the direction  esriGPParameterDirectionOutput ?

Comment: @CharlesSmith, were you able to solve this problem? Even I am getting the exact 500 Internal Error and I am using arcServer 10